# Umbrella term for Invoice, Debit Note, or Credit Note

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language, hypernyms, finance

I would like to find a generic term for a transaction of type **Invoice**, **Debit Note**, or **Credit Note**.

The term `transaction` is already reserved since the context involves other sorts of transactions different from the aforementioned ones.

Comment: In Oracle and SAP FI those are examples of "AR documents."

Comment: They are all called 'vouchers' where I work.

Comment: Would it not be a Bill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all representations of a limited type of [**balance sheet**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balance%20sheet):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : a statement of financial condition at a given date

In this case, they are statements of what is owed by somebody or to somebody. They correspond to a specific subset of an overall account.

---

Note that while *invoice* is both a verb and a noun, *debit note* and *credit note* are only nouns. And if *invoice* is also being treated as a noun, none of those things are actually transactions in the first place.

Invoices, debit notes, and credit notes represent the *result* of one or more transactions, such as a sale or purchase, or other exchange of goods or services.

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is correct. A balance sheet is a stmt of financial *condition*, whereas those documents cause a *change* in the balance, so I would call them transaction notice, or transaction document (if they are in document form.)